# Variable within filename in jinja2

Tags: variables, flask, jinja2

What is the right way to write something like this in jinja2 :

```
{% for items in zipped %}
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/{{items.logo}}') }}" />
```

Notice that `items.logo` is within another variable .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`items.logo` is already a variable. Try:

```
{% for items in zipped %}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/' + items.logo) }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I had this error : `TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}', expected ')'`

Comment: Just a second , I think I should test this again .

Comment: Hey I'm using Django, and when i'm doing the same as above, i'm getting an TemplateSyntaxError. It says Could not parse the remainder: '('static', filename='images/' + card.id)' from 'url_for('static', filename='images/' + card.id)'.